Visual studio strange highlighting on F3
I think I have messed my visual studio setting somehow. Now I can't figure out what is wrong with it.
Whenever I go to search mode. The whole file is highlighted with two character wide bars. Check the image below. If I press escape, then the highlighting is off. So every time I open a new file, if I am in search mode, the file has this strange bars allover.
Can someone tell me what they are and how do I disable them. 
I do not know how I enable this mode. I am guessing an unfortunate keypresses while I put something on my keyboard.

It looks like it is highlighting each line break, and somehow it is also highlighting the character below it. Can you confirm you are not searching for \n with regex mode enabled?

When I used VS2022 Community to create a C ++ console project for operation, I did not have the same situation as you. Please tell me the VS version and project type you use. In addition, you can try to reset the settings to see if it is feasible: Tool> Options> Import and Export Settings> Reset All Settings.
